# Is there a way to restrict deleting rows in a sheet using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, rows

I have an excel sheet in which i want to prevent any rows from being deleted. I have this piece of code that actually does what i want to do but as soon as i run the macro, i am unable to delete any row from any excel workbook.

```
Sub DeleteRowsRestrictions()
Dim xBarControl As CommandBarControl
For Each xBarControl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=293)
    xBarControl.Enabled = False
Next
For Each xBarControl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=294)
    xBarControl.Enabled = False
Next
End Sub
```

Is there a way to prevent deleting rows only from one excel sheet? And not a macro that disables deleting row in all the excel workbooks as my code does?

Thank you :)

Comment: Look into `Worksheet.Protection`

Comment: In the Workbooks Events, there is one everytime you change to a different worksheet. So you can combine this code with `Workbook_SheetActivate` to get the name of the active sheet if it changes,check the name and if it's the one you want to block, then activate your code. IF not, deactivate your code.

Comment: So @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns if i want it to restrict me from deleting rows from the "Parking" spreadhsheet only, i should add 
"Worksheets("Parking").Activate" only?

Comment: You're solution wouldn't stop a user pressing Shift-Space,Control-minus to delete a row

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to avoid deleting rows from `Parking` WorkSheet, in the event `Workbook_SheetActivate` you should put something like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.Name = "Parking" Then
        'CODE TO BLOCK DELETING ROWS
    Else
        'CODE TO ALLOW DELETING ROWS
    End If
End Sub
```

`Sh` is the Worksheet you activate when you change from 1 worksheet to a different one, so when you activate `Parking` then the code will trigger blocking deleting rows. If it's not `PArking` then it will allow deleting rows.

**UPDATE:** You must type this code in the VBA editor, in `ThisWorkbook` Object.

[image]

Once donde, you don't need to pass a parameter, it will work by itself. Events are triggered when a specific action takes places, and don't need the user to pass a parameter (they get it instantly). In this case, the event triggers when user changes from 1 worksheet to another worksheet, and the parameter is the target worksheet (it's stored in the parameter `Sh`) but you don't need to call it with lines of codes. It will trigger by itself.

You can read more info here about this event:

> **[Workbook.SheetActivate event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetactivate)**

If you want to know more about other events, check:

> **[Excel VBA Events](https://powerspreadsheets.com/excel-vba-events/#List-Of-Excel-VBA-Events-Organization-And-Levels-At-Which-You-Can-Monitor-Events)**

**IMPORTANT**: Once you have code in any event, that event will be ready to trigger at **anytime**. In this case, if any other macro of you activates sheet `Parking`, then it will be triggered.

Also, as other users have posted,your codes just prevents deleting rows from command bar, but probably users can still delete rows with rightClick of mouse, or keyboards shortcuts, or other macros.

If you really want to protect that sheet from any deleting, best option is, indeed, @MathieuGuindon answer, protecting the sheet. That way would be more secure.

Comment: Thank you for your help @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns. I am new to VBA and did not really understand what is the parameter i should give to that function?

Comment: Check updated answer, but as I said before, if you really want to protect that sheet from any deleting, best option is, indeed, @MathieuGuindon answer, protecting the sheet. That way would be more secure.

Answer (score 4):

Don't reinvent the wheel, that's already a feature of the Excel object model. You can do this directly in the worksheet, by *protecting* it (I wouldn't bother with a password though, it's easily beaten/hash-collided):

[image: Protect Sheet dialog]

Programmatically, that's done with the `Worksheet.Protect` method - you control what's enabled by providing a `Boolean` value for each permission - `AllowDeletingRows` being one of them:

```
Sheet1.Protect Password:=vbNullString, _
               DrawingObjects:=False, _
               Contents:=False, _
               Scenarios:=False, _
               UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
               AllowFormattingCells:=True, _
               AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
               AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
               AllowInsertingColumns:=True, _
               AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
               AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, _
               AllowDeletingColumns:=False, _
               AllowDeletingRows:=False, _
               AllowSorting:=True, _
               AllowFiltering:=True, _
               AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
```

In my experience the protection alone is a sufficient deterrent for the vast majority of users; a password only serves to eventually be lost/forgotten, plus hard-coding a password in VBA code is rather naive, security-wise: worksheet protection is not a security feature.

Comment: I cannot protect the sheet because it is a shared sheet between a large group of people in which each person has to modify some parts of the sheet @MathieuGuindon

Comment: @CelineN that shouldn't make a difference: you configure the protection accordingly - i.e. disable deleting rows, and enable everything else.